# Finding a number within a string and using it in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, boolean-expression

I need the code to check a string for any number at any point in the string, provide an error message if there is, and then loop back to input. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
 bool isNumber (string accName)
{
                for (int t=0; t < accName.length(); ++t)
                {
                        if (isdigit(accName[t])== false){
                        return false;
                        }

                        return true;
                }
```

I inserted this boolean function into a for statement, but the only output I'm getting is the break from the else statement.

```
 for(i=0; i<999; i++){

        getline(cin, accName);

        if (isNumber(accName) == true){

                cout<<"Account name is invalid, please use letters and spaces only."<<endl;
                }

        else{
        break;
        }
```

I would love some help on this. I've read extensively and can not seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that following line is in the wrong place

```
return true;
```

Move it outside of the `for` loop and it should be fine.

The right way to do this is by using Regular Expressions. If you do not know what that is, [you can start reading here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpp_standard_library/regex.htm)

Comment: There are many ways to do this that don't involve regular expressions and they are just as valid. Regex is not *required*, nor even always the best option.

Comment: Regular expression is not required, but I have to disagree that here in this case it is not the best option. If you read the error message in OP's code. It says a valid account number is some combination of letters and spaces. For matching these kinds of patterns, Regex is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 0):

in your method isNumber you are only checking the first Char of the string.
If it is a Number you return false, if not you return true.
This returning means you exit the method after looking at the first character.

```
bool isNumber (string accName)
{
       for (int t=0; t < accName.length(); ++t)
       {
               if (isdigit(accName[t])!=true){
                   return true;
               }
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a *much* easier way to determine if a string contains all digits, all without any loop, by using [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
bool isNumber (string accName)
{
    return std::all_of(accName.begin(), accName.end(), 
                       [](unsigned char ch){ return std::isdigit(ch); });
}
```

That one line basically says what you are trying to do:  go through the entire string (`accName.begin(), accName.end()`), and make sure *all of* the characters (`std::all_of`) are digits (`std::isdigit`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example to handle all numbers in the string and store them in an array:

```
void isNumber(const std::string& str, std::vector<std::string>& out)
{
    for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        while (isdigit(str[j])) j++  ; //collect the full number
        if (i < j) {
            const char* begin = &str[i];
            const char* end = &str[j];
            std::string s{begin, end};
            out.push_back(s);
            i = j;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> nums;
    isNumber("adbsbd2232sdbsadbasd211bsadasddd77", nums);
    for (auto it : nums) std::cout << it << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

No need to say that you can just break from the number matched in the inner loop and just return if needed.